# Vuejs: Computed prop in object

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

In my vuejs component, I have a data property that looks like this

```
elementData{
  amount: '',
  unit_price: '',
  total: '',
}
```

Now I would like total to be a computed property, as I want to avoid using a watcher on amount & unit price to then update total.

But for some reason I cant seem to find any mentioning in documentation about deep computed properties?

This seems a fairly common use case though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way in the computed section:

```
computed:{
 total: function(){
   return this.unit_price * this.amount
 }
}
```

Remember if you're using strings instead of integers/floats, you must use the parseInt or parseFloat methods to get the proper calculation of the totals

Comment: Yes, this i am aware of. I want it to be in the this.elementData though;

Comment: If you want it in the elementData, you can use a method to modify the total and call it everytime you want it to change. For what i am concerned, there's no other way reactively change the value without a computed or watch property